# Listen for url redirects in the flutter_webview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

Is there a way to listen for the URL redirects in the `flutter_webview`?

`navigationDelegate` is not an option here, cos it is also triggered when the user clicks on some internal link...

So is there any other way?

Comment: You can filter for external links

Comment: @ConstantinN. what do you mean? can you please provide some examples?

Comment: you can listen to navigation events and then chef if the URL is from your domain or not. Then you capture only external links (that does not start by yourdomainurl.com)

Comment: it potentially might work, just if I would deal with my domain. But If I'd like to make it work with any url - it is a bit useless...

Comment: Can't understand want your try to achieve here. if you have then URLs you can match the navigated rout against the URLs

Comment: I am trying to build a kind of browser app. And there are some pages, which redirect you when you open the original URL. This makes back navigation complicated, cos then you go from link B to link A (original), it redirects you again to link B

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plugin [Flutter InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) It lets you control any url users want to navigate to before the navigation starts.

```
InAppWebView(
  ...
  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url){
  if(!url.startsWith(yourdomaine){ // this is not your domain url
  controller.stopLoading();}
},
                      ....
);
```

You can also navigate backward with `controller.back();`

Comment: Due to the tech limitations of the project I am not able to switch from `flutter_webview` plugin. And it's not about the listening of the url and not about blocking some particular domain. I can do the same with `flutter_webview`. But I can't find a possibility to listen when the website auto REDIRECT happened... that's what I need to catch.

Comment: @AndriyAntonov did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @leo_cape nope :(